# how to terminate java application from other java application

Tags: java, kill, terminate

I want to terminate running java application from other java application. can you provide me some idea how to kill / terminate application.
example: java application A is running. I want to terminate it by other java application say B.

Comment: I think that it is OS-Specific. Please, describe more about the system and your code that you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

First launch java app B, and start your application A using B. Use     Runtime.exec(String) or a     ProcessBuilder to start A and store the returned Process object in a variable.

If you now want to kill the subprocess A created by B, use Process.destroy() or Process.destroyForcibly() (whatever fits better).

Comment: Thank you for  the answer. In the above example java app B starts app A.  I want know is there any way to  terminate the java app B (automatic or manually) after it starts app A.